# Как подключить Microsoft Access 2016 к MySQL 8.0?

Tags: mysql, access, odbc, connection

*Данный вопрос задан риторически, для тех кто столкнулся с такой же проблемой, но пока ещё не знает как её решить. Напишу ответ здесь, т.к. больше не знаю где.*
Столкнулась с потребностью управления БД "MySQL 8.00 х64" через СУБД "Access 2016 х64". прочитала пару статей, скачала драйвер "MySQL Connector ODBC 8.0.32 Winx64" с сайта https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/
Скачивала 64-х разрядную версию установщика .msi - Скачала, запустила, Установила. В каталоге Администратора %windir%\system32\odbcad32.exe установленные драйвера отобразились. Но в каталоге "Добавление источника данных" в Аксесс этих драйверов не было(хотя должны были быть).
Я перекопала весь интернет, промчалась с кучей ошибок и через 2 дня нашла ответ. А всё дело было в мелочевке которую ни в одном, попавшемся мне сайте, не уточняли.

Answer (score 0):

*Заранее уточню что у меня Windows 7 сборки 7601 х64-ная версия.
Также тестовая база данных у меня уже была создана, как и пустой Акссес-файл.*

Вообщем, как же так вышло что в одном каталоге драйвер есть, а в другом его нет?

- Ответ не очевиден. Оказывается в Windows 7 есть два каталога Администратора ODBC. Первый находиться по пути %windir%\system32\odbcad32.exe - в нём драйвера были(х64-разрядная версия), а во втором %windir%\SysWOW64\odbcad32.exe - а  этом их не было(тот который отображается в Аксесс).
  Что я сделала: скачала установщик .msi для 32-разрядной версии. При запуске он выдал мне ошибку "Необходимо установить Visual Studio Code 2019", что было странно, ведь пред-идущий установщик такого не просил. Вообщем установить не получилось. И я пошла скачивать zip-архив для 64х разрядной версии.
  Установила,  снова та же беда с отображением. Взяла удалила.
  Установила zip-архив для 32х разрядной версии и О ЧУДО, ситуация стала диаметрально противоположная. **ВНИМАНИЕ** - распаковала содержимое архива в папку "C:\Program Files\MySQL\Connector ODBC 8.0". И уже только тогда запустила установочный-файл "Install.bat".
  Вообщем, как я поняла, %windir%\SysWOW64\odbcad32.exe - отображает драйвера 32х разрядной системы, а %windir%\system32\odbcad32.exe - отображает драйвера 64х разрядной системы.
  И вот что странно: и Access и MySQL были установлены 64х разряные, а работают только с драйвером от 32х разрядной системы )
  Кстати, установка Visual Studio Code - ни как не помогла в исправление работы

Вот ссылки на сайты которыми я пользовалась, и на которых находила ответы на появляющиеся ошибки:

- https://www.1gb.ua/wiki/index.php?title=%D0%94%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%83%D0%BF_%D0%BA_%D0%91%D0%94_mySQL_%D0%B8%D0%B7_Microsoft_Access

http://vasilisc.com/access_mysql

https://gamesqa.ru/kompyutery/oshibka-126-ne-najden-ukazannyj-modul-26026/#_126

https://forum.mista.ru/topic.php?id=687234 *

Если остались вопросы по этому процессу - коментируйте этот вопрос